# How to use variables in SED command (bash)

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have these 3 sed commands:

```
sed -i '10,$s/-.*/-$LOWX:HIGHX+$HIGHX]/' plot.p
sed -i '11,$s/+.*/+$HIGHY]/' plot.p
sed -i '14,$s/+.*/+$HIGHY/' plot.p
```

It is supposed to go to the line denoted by the first value (ie 10, 11, 14) and replace text following the character specified (ie -, +).

Currently, my sed command doesn't recognize the variables ($LOWX, $HIGHX, and $HIGHY), and it just makes the replacement with the literal "$LOWX" for example.

How can I get my sed command to recognize the variables within it?

I saw other answers to similar questions saying to use double quotes but that causes my sed command to be misinterpreted so that it cannot run.

My output:

```
set xr[LOWX-$LOWX:HIGHX+$HIGHX]
set yr[0:HIGHY+$HIGHY]
set ytics 0,1,HIGHY+$HIGHY
```

Desired output:

```
set xr[LOWX-2:HIGHX+2]
set yr[0:HIGHY+1]
set ytics 0,1,HIGHY+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give you your desired output?

```
sed -i "10,\$s/-.*/-$LOWX:HIGHX+$HIGHX]/" plot.p
sed -i "11,\$s/+.*/+$HIGHY]/" plot.p
sed -i "14,\$s/+.*/+$HIGHY/" plot.p
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes will work. Take mine as a quick reference:

```
LAUNCH_APP="./xxx/launch-app.sh"
OLD_PROXY="xx-proxy.uds"
num=$(sed -n "/$OLD_PROXY/=" "$LAUNCH_APP")
sed -i ''${num}'s/^/#/' "$LAUNCH_APP"
```